# How to merge or groupby multiple rows having same value in one of the columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I need help on the below problem,

Problem:

I have below dataframe. In this dataframe, first row is a title, and first column is also a title column. I have three different rows of `5.0`, `10.0`, `20.0` in first column (`Phi`) and I have different values against different values.

```
df_combined

Phi   0.0   10.0     20.0    30.0    40.0    50.0    60.0    70.0
5.0  -6.7   5.6     -2.7    -1.0     4.4    -6.4     6.3    -4.2    
10.0 -3.8   3.1     -1.5    -0.5     2.5    -3.6     3.6    -2.4
20.0  6.3   -5.3     2.6     0.9     -4.2    6.1     -6.0    4.0
5.0  -1.7   5.6     -6.7    -7.0     1.4    -0.4     3.3    -4.2
10.0 -3.8   3.1     -1.5    -4.5     2.5    -1.6     2.6    -4.4
20.0  6.3   -1.3     2.6     0.9     -4.2    6.1     -7.0    4.0
5.0  -0.7   5.6     -6.7    -7.0     1.4    -0.4     3.3    -4.2
10.0 -3.8   3.1     -6.5    -2.5     6.5    -8.6     4.6    -3.4
20.0  6.3   -1.3     2.6     3.9     -3.2    4.1     -5.0    9.0
```

**Expected output:**
I want my dataframe lookimg like this where values against `5.0` come together. And same for `10.0` and `20.0`. I do not want to aggregate or count or addition of these values. I just want these columns come together next to each other.

```
Phi   0.0   10.0     20.0    30.0    40.0    50.0    60.0    70.0
     -6.7   5.6     -2.7    -1.0     4.4    -6.4     6.3    -4.2
5.0  -1.7   5.6     -6.7    -7.0     1.4    -0.4     3.3    -4.2
     -0.7   5.6     -6.7    -7.0     1.4    -0.4     3.3    -4.2

10.0 -3.8   3.1     -1.5    -4.5     2.5    -1.6     2.6    -4.4
     -3.8   3.1     -6.5    -2.5     6.5    -8.6     4.6    -3.4
      6.3   -5.3     2.6     0.9     -4.2    6.1     -6.0    4.0

20.0  6.3   -1.3     2.6     0.9     -4.2    6.1     -7.0    4.0
      6.3   -1.3     2.6     3.9     -3.2    4.1     -5.0    9.0
```

I tried `groupby` function like below,

```
df_combined2 = df_combined.groupby(df_combined['Phi'])
```

But got below error,

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001BE9EC2BDC0>
```

What should I do?

Comment: I think you should just sort te data frame want [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

sort the values by PHI and then make the repeating values as empty

```
# sort the dataframe
df=df.sort_values('Phi')

#to make repetitive values under PHI as empty
df['Phi']=df['Phi'].mask(df['Phi'].eq(df['Phi'].shift(1)), "")
df
```

OR

```
# sort the dataframe
df=df.sort_values('Phi')

# makes PHI as empty when diff from previous value is 0
df['Phi']=df['Phi'].mask(df['Phi'].diff().eq(0), '')
df
```

```
    Phi      0.0    10.0    20.0    30.0    40.0    50.0    60.0    70.0
0   5.0     -6.7    5.6     -2.7    -1.0    4.4     -6.4    6.3     -4.2
3           -1.7    5.6     -6.7    -7.0    1.4     -0.4    3.3     -4.2
6           -0.7    5.6     -6.7    -7.0    1.4     -0.4    3.3     -4.2
1   10.0    -3.8    3.1     -1.5    -0.5    2.5     -3.6    3.6     -2.4
4           -3.8    3.1     -1.5    -4.5    2.5     -1.6    2.6     -4.4
7           -3.8    3.1     -6.5    -2.5    6.5     -8.6    4.6     -3.4
2   20.0     6.3    -5.3    2.6     0.9     -4.2    6.1     -6.0    4.0
5            6.3    -1.3    2.6     0.9     -4.2    6.1     -7.0    4.0
8            6.3    -1.3    2.6     3.9     -3.2    4.1     -5.0    9.0
```